# Exchange two nodes in LinkedList

Tags: .net, .net-2.0, linked-list

I encountered a simple "problem": Exchange two nodes in a LinkedList (**.NET 2**) How can I do it in a "optimal" way. Thanks!

```
Dim label1 As New Label()
Dim label2 As New Label()
'... some code
Dim testList As New LinkedList(Of Label)
'... some code
Dim node1 As LinkedListNode(Of Label) = testList.Find(label1)
Dim node2 As LinkedListNode(Of Label) = testList.Find(label2)


If ??? Then
  ' exchange two nodes
End If
```

is the

```
node1.Value = label2
node2.Value = label1
```

sufficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the implementation, but if your nodes have simply one value (in addition to the next and previous links), you can just swap the values.

Comment: :) Ok, Svante was the first with the idea.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
testList.AddAfter(node1, node2.Value)
testList.AddAfter(node2, node1.Value)
testList.Remove(node1)
testList.Remove(node2)
```

This is four O(1) operations, and will work whether the nodes are at the start or end of the list. The only problem is that if node1 == node2 it will add two new nodes, remove the existing one, and then throw an exception as it tries to remove it again. Obviously this isn't a problem if your algorithm makes sure they're different to start with...

EDIT: Doh. The MSDN docs misled me into thinking that `Value` is read-only. (It says: "Gets the value contained in the node" - rather than "Gets or sets [...]." Actually it's writable, so you *could* do:

```
Label tmp = node1.Value
node1.Value = node2.Value
node2.Value = tmp
```

On the other hand, anything that already has a reference to the nodes will see the change, which *may* not be what you want. Of course, anything that already has a reference to the nodes will end up seeing nodes which are no longer part of the list using my first approach...

Comment: what do you think about
    Dim tempNode1Val As Label = node1.Value
    node1.Value = node2.Value
    node2.Value = tempNode1Val

Comment: @jon, I see too, in the XML comments for Value *Obtains* only. Usually is wrote *Obtains or defines* :)

Comment: Thanks, Jon! The "algorithm" is simpler that I imagined :)